# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a GridView connected with the EntityDataSource.

EntityDataSource has a internal parameter for Where Parameters. All is working fine till this point.

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceListAuthors" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel"
        DefaultContainerName="CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel" EnableFlattening="False"
        EntitySetName="CmsAuthors" EntityTypeFilter="" OrderBy="it.FirstName" Select="it.AuthorId, it.UserId, it.FirstName, it.LastName, it.NoteInternal, it.ContentAuthor"
        Where="it.UserId = @ActiveUser">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

---

I use an Event RowDataBound an Entity Framework to retrieve a value for every single row and execute some logic.

As soon as I run the code I receive this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord' to type 'WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsAuthor'.
```

It seems to me when adding parameters to EntityDataSource smt is changing so I am not able to use EF as before 
Any idea? Thanks Guys!

---

```
        protected void uxListAuthorsDisplayer_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
            switch (e.Row.RowType)
            {
                // In case type of row is DataRow (a data row of GridView) 
                case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                    // Display friendly User's Name instead of his Guid
                    // Retrive underlying data from a single row rappresented in GridView (use Entity Framwork)                
                    WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsAuthor myRow = (WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsAuthor)e.Row.DataItem;
                    // Retrive the Guid for a User in a specific row
                    Guid myUserGuid = (Guid)myRow.UserId;
                    // Find out used UserName using Guid UserId
                    MembershipUser mySelectedUser = Membership.GetUser(myUserGuid);
                    // Write friendly User's Name instead of his Guid value in a specific Grid View Cell
                    e.Row.Cells[3].Text = mySelectedUser.UserName;

                    // Disable Delete Button if a Content has associated an Author
                    // Use Entity Framwork for retriving data - Create a "Context" for a single Row
                    using (CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel context = new CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel())
                    {
                        // Find out Row Id and create an varaible to store it
                        int myWorkingRowId = myRow.AuthorId;
                        // Find the Edit Link
                        HyperLink myEditLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("uxLinkEditButton");
                        // Find the Delete Button
                        LinkButton myDeleteButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("uxLinkDeleteButton");
                        // Find the System Note Label
                        Label mySystemNote = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("uxSystemNoteDisplayer");
                        // Use of Lamba Espression with EF to check if an Author is associated with a Content
                        CmsContent authorIdInContent = context.CmsContents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AuthorId == myWorkingRowId);
                        // Make visible or invisible the Delete Button if an Author is associated to a Content
                        if (authorIdInContent != null)
                        {
                            myDeleteButton.Visible = false;
                            mySystemNote.Text = "Author is being used in Contents";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            myDeleteButton.Visible = true;
                        }

                        // Programmatically Limiting Functionality depending on User's Roles
                        myEditLink.Visible = User.IsInRole("CMS-ADMINISTRATOR") || User.IsInRole("CMS-AUTHOR") || User.IsInRole("CMS-EDITOR");
                        myDeleteButton.Visible = User.IsInRole("CMS-ADMINISTRATOR");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wrap your code really is not readable.

Answer (score 1):

Read Diego Vega's blog post on binding EntityDataSource in the RowDataBound event:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2008/05/13/entitydatasource-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap.aspx

You are running into the fourth scenario of his "rules for wrapping".

> Finally, if you set the Select property to do a projection (i.e. "it.CustomerID, it.CustomerName", you get DbDataRecord regardless of how you start your query.

You will not be able to get the source entity. You have to treat your DataItem as something like a DataRow.

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

    Dim rowCmsAuthor = CType(e.Row.DataItem, Data.Common.DbDataRecord)

    Dim myUserID As Integer = rowCmsAuthor("UserId")

End If
```

Alternatively you may be able to just remove the `Select` property from your EntityDataSource. Try to use scenario 1 or 2 of Diego's rules for wrapping.